# MYSQL combining queries for optimization

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I'd like to combine several queries into as few as possible.  This is for a video game I'm writing.
Note
-spawn_id is the id of an entity that creates the bad guy on the level at a given place on a map.
-* from spawns includes the spawn_id, max quantity of bad guys to spawn(quantity), and the type of bad guy to spawn (mob_id)to spawn them and an ID to tell it what type of bad guy to spawn
the game is online so Id rather minimize the number of queries

It would be nice if I could subtract count (number already in game) from quantity(maximum quantity to have in game) where spawn ID are the same and return that all together

Would be even better if I could return the spawn ID quantity to spawn and the type of bad guy together as one row like this

SELECT spawn_id, COUNT(*) as 'count' FROM game_moblist  GROUP BY spawn_id"
returns...

```
spawn_id count
======== =====
1         2
```

TABLE spawns contains

```
spawn_id quantity mob_id level
======== ======== ====== =====
1        5        1      2
```

mob_id poitns to TABLE mobs which has

```
mob_id ...stats for mob_id
====== ===================
1      unique stats for mob#1
```

I'd like to return something like this:

```
spawn_id   quantity_to_spawn   mob_id   ...stats for mob_id
========   =================   ======
1          3                   1        unique stats for mob#1
```

which means I must insert 3 rows selected from mobs which I don't mind doing a second query for so I can multiply stats by level to create a bad guy in the game that is level 2... essentially level 2 means the stats are twice as high as the number stored in 'mobs' table

Here is my code so far I could finish it but I'd rather try to reduce the number of queries first.

```
    sql= "SELECT spawn_id, COUNT(*) as 'count' FROM game_moblist  GROUP BY spawn_id"
       connection.query(sql, function(err, spawncount, fields) {
          sql= "SELECT  * FROM spawns"
          connection.query(sql, function(err, spawns, fields) {
             for (i=0;i<spawns.length;i++){
                if (spawns[i].next_spawn < new Date().getTime()){
               for (j=0;spawncount.length;j++){
                      if (spawncount[j].spawn_id ==spawns[i].spawn_id&&spawncount[j].count<spawns[i].quantity){
                         quantity_to_spawn = spawns[i].quantity -spawncount[j].count
                         //fetch spawns[i].mob_id mob from mobs table
                         for(k=0;k<quantity_to_spawn;k++){
                         //multiply for level
                         //insert into moblist
                         }
                      }
                   }
                }
             }
          });
       });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT 
 spawn_id,
 quantity - COUNT(game_moblist.(spawn_id)) AS quantity_to_spawn,
 mobs.*
FROM spawn_contains
LEFT JOIN mobs USING (mob_id)
LEFT JOIN game_moblist USING (spawn_id)
GROUP BY spawn_id
```

Comment: I added a parenthesis on quantity and changed a table spawn_contains to spawns
SELECT spawn_id, (
quantity - COUNT( game_moblist.spawn_id )
) AS quantity_to_spawn, mobs . * 
FROM spawns
LEFT JOIN mobs
USING ( mob_id ) 
LEFT JOIN game_moblist
USING ( spawn_id ) 
GROUP BY spawn_id
LIMIT 0 , 30
Thank you that really helped me understand some of the MySQL I was less familiar with too.

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly the reason for using a LEFT or INNER JOIN.  Please read up on how those SQL functions work - you will greatly upgrade your SQL knowledge that way!

The basic idea is that if you have two tables, say, Items:

```
item      name
=====     =====
1         Sword of Ultimate Power
2         Big Freaking Gun
```

and locations:

```
location  name
========  =====
1         Fortress of Solitude
2         Quendor
```

and then want a table item_locations that keeps track of which items are in which locations:

```
item_id    location_id
========   ============
1          2
2          1
```

then you can use an expression like

```
SELECT item.name, location.name FROM items LEFT JOIN item_locations AS il ON (item.id = il.item_id) LEFT JOIN locations ON (il.location_id = locations.id)
```

and then you will return a list like:

```
item.name                  location.name
===============            ================
Sword of Ultimate Power    Quendor
Big Freaking Gun           Fortress of Solitude
```

This also has the advantage of you being able to add mutliple indexes into your various tables to optimize the actual row lookups.

You can also use views to make new virtual tables that provide these relationships automatically.

Comment: I agree and I tried the following query 
SELECT  spawn_id, COUNT(*) as 'count' FROM game_moblist  
LEFT JOIN game_moblist
ON spawns.spawn_id=game_moblist.spawn_id
GROUP BY spawn_id
but it said #1066 - Not unique table/alias: 'game_moblist'
I understand left join to a degree but it is a little beyond my level to do arithmatic in mysql and return a combined row with quantity minus count and a left join on sapwn id  then a second left join on mob_id